# React Star Rating Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a simple star rating component to make users able to review my books.

Here's the component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { FaStar } from 'react-icons/fa'

const StarRating = (props) => {
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            {[...Array(5)].map((star, i) => {
                const ratingValue = i + 0;
                return (
                    <label>
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="rating"
                            onClick={() => setRating(props.ratingValue)}
                        />
                        <FaStar color={ratingValue < rating ? "#01af93" : "#bbb"} />
                    </label>
                )
            })}
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

export default StarRating
```

So, if somebody clicks on the Stars the rating will appear (using an onClick handler).

I would like to display the ratings without the onClick handler now.

I've tried simply to add `value={props.ratingValue}` instead of `onClick={() => setRating(props.ratingValue)}` but it doesn't work.

Hope someone can help with what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I've used these before but would like to do that without any packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move `onClick` handler and `value` to the parent container class. So changing state and keeping current input value must be done in your parent container. Below I share a code snippet for your sample.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa";

const StarRating = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      {Array(5)
        .fill(0)
        .map((_, idx) => (
          <label key={idx}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="rating"
              onChange={() => props.setRating(idx)}
              value={props.ratingValue}
              checked={idx === props.ratingValue}
            />
            <FaStar color={idx < 3 ? "#01af93" : "#bbb"} />
          </label>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export const RatingContainer = () => {
  const [rate, setRate] = useState(3);

  return (
    <div>
      <StarRating setRating={(val) => setRate(val)} ratingValue={rate} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Going to try that now! :)

Comment: Works! Thanks for saving me a lot of time!!

Answer (score 0):

**work for me try this**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
    
    const RatingStar = () => {
      const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
    
      const handleRatingPress = (selectedRating) => {
        setRating(selectedRating);
      };
    
      const renderStars = () => {
        const stars = [];
        const totalStars = 5;
    
        for (let i = 1; i <= totalStars; i++) {
          const starIconName =
            i <= rating
              ? 'star'
              : i - rating <= 0.5
              ? 'star-half-o'
              : 'star-o';
    
          stars.push(
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={i}
              onPress={() => handleRatingPress(i)}
            >
              <Icon name={starIconName} size={30} color="#FFD700" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }
    
        return stars;
      };
    
      return (
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, marginBottom: 10 }}>
            Rating: {rating.toFixed(1)}
          </Text>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>{renderStars()}</View>
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default RatingStar;
```